# Documentation topic that has been deleted should have a reason

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

Recently, an entire topic was deleted in the Ruby Documentation. When I looked at it, I couldn't find any reason about why it was deleted. So, if I disagree with the removal, what stops me to rollback it?

I won't do it, as I think there was a reason to delete it. But I think that an explanation is really necessary in these cases. Think of people who have worked hard on that topic, it would be annoying to wake up and see your examples deleted and not knowing why.

**tl;dr**
There should be and explanation attached to a documentation topic that has been deleted.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329596/examples-deleted-from-documentation/329672#329672 (there should be a reason, it's just not currently very obvious how to find it)

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks! Nevertheless it should be more explicit when an entire topic is being deleted